# Spring Data JPA - "could not initialize proxy - no Session" - With Methods marked as transactional

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, c3p0

I have a model that has a pretty large graph of sub entities and hibernate ends up making around 9 statements to lazily fetch all of the data needed but about 4 levels deep I get a "could not initialize proxy - no Session" error and I am not sure why.

Controller

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/plans", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<PlanPresenter> show(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
  List<PlanPresenter> planPresenters = new ArrayList<>();

  CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Plan> planQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Plan.class);
  Root<Plan> root = planQuery.from(Plan.class);

  if (request.getParameter("region") != null || request.getParameter("group") != null) {
    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    if (request.getParameter("region") != null) {
      criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Plan_.region), request.getParameter("region")));
    }

    if (request.getParameter("group") != null) {
      criteria.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Plan_.groupCode), request.getParameter("group")));
      criteria.add(root.get(Plan_.planSetId).in(groupPlanSetIds));
    } else {
      criteria.add(root.get(Plan_.planSetId).in(currentPlanSetIds));
    }

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(planQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[]{}))));

    for (Plan plan : (List<Plan>)query.getResultList()) {
      planPresenters.add(new PlanPresenter(plan));
    }
  }

  return planPresenters;
}
```

Presenter

```
public class PlanPresenter {
  public String id;
  public String plan_set_id;
  public String region;
  public String name;
  public String description;
  public HashMap<String, Object> details = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  public PlanPresenter(Plan plan) throws Exception {
    this.id = String.valueOf(plan.id);
    this.plan_set_id = String.valueOf(plan.planSetId);
    this.region = plan.region.trim();
    this.name = plan.getName();
    this.description = plan.getDescription();

    this.details.put("spanish_plan", plan.isSpanishPlan());
    this.details.put("mutually_exclusive", plan.isMutuallyExclusive());
    this.details.put("group_plan", plan.isGroupPlan());
    this.details.put("group_code", plan.groupCode.trim());
    this.details.put("family_plan", plan.isFamilyPlan());
    this.details.put("price", plan.getPrice());
    this.details.put("enrollment_fee", plan.getEnrollmentFee());
    this.details.put("riders", plan.getRiders());
  }
}
```

Plan

```
@Entity
public class Plan implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7639611964474770505L;

  private static List<String> familyPlanShortNames = Arrays.asList("ABCD");
  @Transient
  private String description = "";

  (Column definitions)

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "XXXX", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  public PlanDetail planDetail;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "XXXX", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
  @OrderBy("XXXX")
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  public List<Rider> riders;

  public String getName() {
    return this.planDetail != null ? this.planDetail.longName.trim() : null;
  }

  public Boolean isSpanishPlan() {
    return this.language.trim().equals("ES");
  }

  public Boolean isMutuallyExclusive() {
    return this.mutuallyExclusive.trim().equals("Y");
  }

  public Boolean isGroupPlan() {
    return this.groupCode != null && !this.groupCode.trim().equals("");
  }

  public Boolean isFamilyPlan() {
    return familyPlanShortNames.contains(this.planDetail.shortName.trim());
  }

  public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return this.planDetail != null ? this.planDetail.price.setScale(2) : null;
  }

  public BigDecimal getEnrollmentFee() {
    return this.planDetail != null ? this.planDetail.enrollmentFee.setScale(2) : null;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    if (this.planDetail != null && this.planDetail.brochureSections != null) {
      this.planDetail.brochureSections.forEach((brochureSection) -> {
        if (brochureSection.type.trim().equals("P1") && brochureSection.order == 1) {
          this.description = this.description + " " + brochureSection.text.trim();
        }
      });
    }

    return this.description.trim();
  }

  public List<HashMap<String, Object>> getRiders() {
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> riders = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    if (this.riders != null && this.riders.size() > 0) {
      this.riders.forEach((rider) -> {
        HashMap<String, Object> planRider = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        planRider.put("name", rider.getName());
        planRider.put("price", rider.getPrice());
        planRider.put("description", rider.getDescription());
        riders.add(planRider);
      });
    }
    return riders;
  }
}
```

Plan Detail

```
@Entity
public class PlanDetail implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2256881691562712018L;

  (Column definitions)

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "XXXX", referencedColumnName = "XXXX", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
  @OrderBy("XXXX")
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  public List<BrochureSection> brochureSections;
}
```

Brochure Section

```
@Entity
public class BrochureSection implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1856191232387921427L;

  (Column definitions)
}
```

Exception

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.models.PlanDetail.brochureSections, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at com.models.Plan.getDescription(Plan.java:100) ~[classes/:?]
at com.presenters.v2.PlanPresenter.<init>(PlanPresenter.java:20) ~[classes/:?]
at com.controllers.v2.PlansController.show(PlansController.java:64) ~[classes/:?]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The peace of code would help. Simple approach what would help you to return VO object from service or change the FetchType.

Comment: So, if I change the fetch type to EAGER I can get it to work, BUT I don't really want to for performance reasons.

Comment: As per the error and the code if fails at brochure section. Can you add hibernate.instance(this.plandetail.getbrochure()) in your getdescription() method. As this attribute is lazy loaded your code in get description cannot find it so in order to use it you have to load it first and do whatever you want to do with it. Please let me know if this helps. Just to point I am also new in hibernate and have encountered this error personally and was able to resolve this way

Comment: How do I get the hibernate variable in that model?

Comment: For starters it is imho a bad idea to make your web layer the transactional boundary. That said your controller isn't transactional, there is nothing transaction related in your stack trace. Add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to a configuration class loaded in the same context as the controller (or `<tx:annotation-driven />` if using XML). If you have that but is loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` it won't work AOP is only applied in the same application context.

Comment: links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675303/how-to-force-initialize-a-hibernate-jpa-proxy-to-use-it-in-a-json-call, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368563/jpa-equivalent-command-to-hibernate-initialize, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359306/how-to-load-lazy-fetched-items-from-hibernate-jpa-in-my-controller,  http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/, http://www.coderanch.com/t/219333/ORM/databases/JPA-force-loading-nested-lazy

Comment: Fast solution: `myEntity.getListOfThings().size();` Force JPA to initialize collection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574236/how-to-fix-org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-prox)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

If you would like to keep **Lazy Load** and you are using Spring Boot, just add the config below in your **application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Comment: Just because I am curious. Where did you find this?

Comment: actually it's an anti-pattern, for further explanation please take a look at https://vladmihalcea.com/2016/09/05/the-hibernate-enable_lazy_load_no_trans-anti-pattern/

Comment: @darkled - I think there's actually a difference between "there are potential performance implications that you should be aware of before using this" and "it's an antipattern".  Not every application needs the highest possible performance from its database access code, and sometimes not having to spend hours of developer time defining which properties are loaded ahead of time with which queries is more important.

Comment: @Jules agreed, not all of the applications need the highest performance, but it's an example of a solution that is usually ineffective and risks being highly counterproductive (which is the definition of the anti-patterns on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Comment: there are surely another way to fix issue? maybe write directly in jpql the query?

Comment: This is interesting information, but the question is more about why "@Transactional" is not enough to keep transaction open imo.

Comment: I have the same question as Tristan. The contract of \@Transactional is to keep the transaction and thus the session open until at least by the end of the method annotated by \@Transactional. So this hack shouldn't be needed, and if used, will result in possibly a second transaction being started which is undesirable.

Comment: this solution is an anti-pattern

Comment: This solution does work. Can you please provide a bit of explanation here? Also in the link you provided, Vladmi Halcea stated that `Although the hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans configuration property is a lesser-known setting, it’s good to know why you shouldn’t employ it in your data access layer code.`

Comment: Didn't work for me, but @Transactional did https://stackoverflow.com/a/49900305/426805

Comment: It's great for use in tests where you select on the repository to assert the properties of an entity: `@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true")`

Answer (score 5):

The lazy loading can be kept, without the setting the enable_lazy_load_no_trans parameter.  The simplest solution I found was @NamedEntityGraph while using Spring Data JPA. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs

The downside was I could not have more than one collection in the @NamedEntityGraph.  Adding a second collection resulted in an exception `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags:`

Therefore, if you don't want to use the anti-pattern, and only have one collection you are trying to load, the @NamedEntityGraph and @EntityGrpah works with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Well you indeed can avoid the multipleBagException by using Sets rather than Collections or Lists...

Comment: Using sets instead of lists is a bad idea according to https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/

Answer (score 5):

Adding `@Transactional` over method works for me

Comment: Same, didn't know why some service methods need some methods don't.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true` it is an anti-pattern and highly recommend to avoid to use it.

`could not initialize proxy` exception will occur often when child class contains
`@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` in your relationship.

I recommend to use `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in your relationship instead of using `LAZY`. It is not the best way but it is far better than using anti-pattern.

Comment: FetchType.EAGER worked for me. I think your answer should get more votes, it's easy to speak about anti-pattern, but you actually provided an alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

just add `@Transactional` above the method in your service and ensure the import use for Transactional from **SpringBoot** not from **jakarta**

Comment: Adding @Transactional to the service class instead of individual methods works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a class with several ManyToOne and ManyToMany relations. Ergo several lists of objects needed to be loaded from database. I resolved the issue by transforming those objects to DTOs.
Instead of transferring lists of objects, which may be linked to other objects you pass a list of DTOs that contain only primitives and Strings
This is a huge performance booster