# LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I use `spring-data-jpa` with `spring-boot(v2.0.0.RELEASE)`, I just wrote a CRUD demo on MySQL, but an exception occurs during runtime, source code as follows:

**Source code**

*User.java*

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    ...getter&setter
}
```

*UserRepository.java*

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

*UserServiceTest.java*

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void getUserById() throws Exception{
        userRepository.getOne(1);
    }

}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: ***
    password: ***
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: ********
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

**Exception details**

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:155)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:268)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
at cn.shuaijunlan.sdnsecuritysystem.domain.po.User_$$_jvstc90_0.getUsername(User_$$_jvstc90_0.java)
at cn.shuaijunlan.sdnsecuritysystem.service.UserServiceTest.getUserById(UserServiceTest.java:33)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
```

> I try to another method `userRepository.findOne(1)`, it can run successfully.

Comment: Try to add @Transactional to your test method...

Comment: @Cepr0 Add `@Transactional` to the unit test method, it can run successfully, can you give more details about why it can run without exception?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can add `@Transactional` annotation to your test method to avoid this exception.

Method `getOne` return the 'reference' (proxy) of the entity which properties can be lazy loaded. See it [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/5ec2d41c446f0b6855b141af405e5f8552b5c539/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L252) - it uses `getReference` method of `EntityManager`. From it javadoc:

> Get an instance, whose state may be lazily fetched.

In Spring the implementation of `EntityManager` is [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/SessionImpl.java) - so without the Session the Spring can not get this method.

To have a session you can just create a transaction...

Comment: But if my test uses the @Transactional annotation, doesn't that mean the test is only valid for transactional queries?

Comment: @MiguelMunoz every method in JpaRepository is [transactional](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java)

Comment: In my case, adding `@Transactional` to the service itself helped

Comment: But why is it helpful at this point? Does the @Transaction annotation create a session? AFAIK this annotation handle rollback things but maybe my knowledge isn't enough.

Answer (score 4):

Your test should be like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)    


@SpringBootTest
@Transactional    

public class QuestionTesting {   

    @Test    
    public void test() {    

    }    
}
```

Comment: Please try to use code block formatting on all the code in your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 3):

just add in application properties spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A couple of recommendations not to do this... https://thorben-janssen.com/lazyinitializationexception/ and https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hibernate-enable_lazy_load_no_trans-anti-pattern/   - more discussion on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38690930/444738

Answer (score -2):

In the  service class please add a setter for entity manager by using the annoattion @PersistenceContext. To be specific, use

```
 @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
```

In this way, you can access lazy property.

Comment: Your example would be more helpful if you included whatever it is you're annotating. Do I apply this to the class? And what do you mean by "the service class"?

Comment: Service class is the class having the @Service annotation. I assume you knoe spring containers and spring classes.

Comment: The question does not have a service class.