# Spring Jpa selective update

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to selectively update fields in a table using spring jpa. According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39746931/2739681 this should be possible with a simple function like:

```
 public TestEntity update(UUID uuid, String string2new) {
    TestEntity testEntity = testEntityRepository.getOne(uuid);
    testEntity.setString2(string2new);
    return testEntityRepository.save(testEntity);
}
```

where TestEntity is (omitted getter and setter):

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {

    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    private String string;
    private String string2;
}
```

However, my test code:

```
@Test
public void selectiveUpdate2() {
    TestEntity testEntity = testEntityRepository.save(TestEntity.builder().string("lulu").string2("lala").build());
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.findAll());
    testEntityService.updateString2(testEntity.getId(), "lele");
    System.out.println(testEntityRepository.findAll());
}
```

However I got an exception as following:

> [TestEntity(id=61a24efc-877f-4a89-9e75-a9933fe7c04c, string=lulu, string2=lala)]
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [com.example.test_db_zeug.TestEntity#61a24efc-877f-4a89-9e75-a9933fe7c04c] - no Session
>       at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:169)
>       at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
>       at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:45)
>       at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95)
>       at com.example.test_db_zeug.TestEntity$HibernateProxy$GilcmZfo.setString2(Unknown Source)
>       at com.example.test_db_zeug.TestEntityService.update(TestEntityService.java:39)
>       at com.example.test_db_zeug.TestDbZeugApplicationTests.selectiveUpdate(TestDbZeugApplicationTests.java:27)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Comment: You can try to add @Transactional annotation to your test method.

Comment: This indeed helps. But what does it mean, and how can I prevent this error in general?

Comment: From the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894587/lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session).