# Spring One-To-Many relationship throws Exception : org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I try to create a simple relationship between two entities with spring. There is one `User` entity that holds many `profile` entities.

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Profile> profiles;

    public List<Profile> getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }

    public void setProfiles(List<Profile> profiles) {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }
}
```

**Profile Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Profile {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

When I try to find a profile with `this.profileRepository.findById(id).get()` inside a `@RestController` I get this error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: User.profiles, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: User.profiles, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->User["profiles"])]
The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is not working? I followed [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-relationships) tutorial.

Comment: The transaction is closed. If one knows one needs the related object, the relations should be fetched eagerly instead of lazily.

Comment: There are no "rest controllers" in this tutorial (except the repositories... which have "built in" controllers),  probably you are just missing a `@Transactional` annotation on your controller class/method ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49894587/592355)) ... [advanced issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36583185/592355)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as ***Mandar*** said, you can resolve it by `eager fetch`. But if you don't want to fetch all I mean `eager fetch`, then you have to initialize them for lazy fetch like this to the related class, your Profile class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@Entity
public class Profile implements Serializable{
//
//
.. your other stuffs
}
```

***Edit:*** also change your User entity like this:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Profile> profiles = new LinkedHashSet<Profile>();
//...other stufs..
.
.
}
```

Hope, this will help!

Comment: As an aside: I would generally advice to separate the business entities from the persistence entities, as well as the DTOs. So really, this one class should be three classes: a DTO for (external) representation, a business entity and a persistence entity.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. As you described I've added the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to the profile entity. But It's still the same problem. Can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: @Turing85 Can you explain the meaning of business entities to me?

Comment: did you add this whole thing `@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})` ?
Ok, this initialize for lazily fetched data in their deserialization process as those data does not fetched the first time you call for that object.
Also, check my edit please

Comment: Yes, I've added the whole annotation

Comment: please check the updates.. I have implemneted Serializtion for both entities and initiazlied hashSet for oneToMany relation

Comment: @Markus that is out-of-scope for this question. In essence, it represents business data that is independent from the persistence- and representation-(web-)layer

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue.
But I was getting the error of " Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialise a collection of role:"
because I did not have declared toString method in the viewDTO

Below are the things which I had done

1. declared @Transactional in service method.
2. declared the field in persistence DTO  as below

```html
 @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    @JsonIgnore
    @ElementCollection
    protected List<String> someField;
```

where

```html
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> list) {
        return String.join(",", list);
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
    }

}
```

1. was creating the viewDTO out of persistence DTO and setting the viewDTO in response entity .