# Quartz Integration test and transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I try create integration test on Quartz scheduler.

I have 2 tables: **events** and **tasks**. Scheduler create **task** by **event** by cron trigger.

```
@SneakyThrows
@Test
public void taskGenerationBeanTest() {
    RequestData request = requestBuilder(str(), str(), str()).build();
    String orderId = String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
    Event event1 = getEvent("type1", request, orderId);
    Event event2 = getEvent("type2", request, orderId);

    eventRepository.save(event1);
    eventRepository.save(event2);

    Thread.sleep(20000);
    List<Event> events = eventRepository.findAll();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    List<Task> actual = taskRepository.findAll();

    assertAll(
            () -> assertEquals(2, actual.size()),
            () -> assertTrue(actual.stream().anyMatch(t ->
                    "type1".equals(t.getEvent().getEventType()))),
            () -> assertEquals(event1.getOrderId(), actual.get(0).getEvent().getOrderId())
    );
}
```

Firstly, I get exception:

> could not initialize proxy - no Session

I use this answer [Spring Data JPA - "could not initialize proxy - no Session" - With Methods marked as transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583185/spring-data-jpa-could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-with-methods-marke) and add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`
to my test config.
So now I get another problem - my test sometimes work true, but more often it falls, because it create only 1 **task**.

Method, that executed by **Quartz**:

```
@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
public int createAndSaveTasks(EventType eventType) {
    List<Task> tasks = eventService.getEvent(eventType)
            .stream()
            .map(Task::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    taskRepository.saveAll(tasks);
    return tasks.size();
}
```

So how properly create Integration test with Quarts and transactions?

Comment: Most probably test class does not have transaction so you can not get t.getEvent() or orderId()

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez after adding spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true  I can get Event from Task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test class uses findAll method of repository and if you try to get LAZY initialized method, you can get this exception.

In the assertions :

```
t.getEvent().getEventType() // can throw it
actual.get(0).getEvent() // can throw it
```

To avoid it maybe you can make it transactional or eager fetch type can be prefered.

under REPEATABLE READ the second SELECT is guaranteed to display at least the rows that were returned from the first SELECT unchanged. New rows may be added by a concurrent transaction in that one minute, but the existing rows cannot be deleted nor changed.

[Difference between "read commited" and "repeatable read"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034976/difference-between-read-commited-and-repeatable-read)

Comment: I can't do it Eager, because all works correct, the problem only with Integration test

Comment: Actually it is related to ISOLATION level and can you change it to READ_COMMITED. Second query can not be updated in concurent way when repeatable_read